# Sign up bootstrap carousel indicators does not change photo when clicked

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a carousel with four slides.
The slider controls and the indicators are shown but not working.
Can't navigate to next or previous photo of the slider.
Can't find the mistake.
Any ideas??

This is my code:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-default"> 

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="">Service</a></li>
<li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
</div><!--navbar-->
<div id="the-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">   
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#the-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#the-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#the-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#the-slider" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>


<div class="carousel-inner">

<div class="item active">

<img src="pic/g800x400.gif" alt="pic1">
    </div> <!--item-1 -->

<div class="item">

<img src="pic/pic1.jpg"  alt="pic2">
     </div> <!--item-2 -->
<div class="item">

<img src="pic/pic2.jpg" alt="pic3">
    </div> <!--item-3 -->

<div class="item">

<img src="pic/pic3.jpg" alt="pic4">
    </div> <!--item-4 -->
</div> <!-- carousel-inner -->

<!--controls-->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#the-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>

<a class="right carousel-control" href="#the-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> 
</a>


</div> <!--the-slider -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to include javascript, in order it to work

Comment: inspect your webpage in chrome and check the console to find out errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these two scripts in your head section

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

include jquery

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

include bootstrapmin.js

Answer (score 0):

**Hi George Kougentakos-jones.This may help you**......

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--navbar-->
        <div id="the-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#the-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#the-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#the-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#the-slider" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>


            <div class="carousel-inner">

                <div class="item active">

                    <img src="pic/g800x400.gif" alt="pic1" style="width:100%">
                </div> <!--item-1 -->

                <div class="item">

                    <img src="pic/pic1.jpg" alt="pic2" style="width:100%">
                </div> <!--item-2 -->
                <div class="item">

                    <img src="pic/pic2.jpg" alt="pic3" style="width:100%">
                </div> <!--item-3 -->

                <div class="item">

                    <img src="pic/pic3.jpg" alt="pic4" style="width:100%">
                </div> <!--item-4 -->
            </div> <!-- carousel-inner -->
            <!--controls-->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#the-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>

            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#the-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>


        </div>
    </div> <!--the-slider -->
</body>
</html>`
```